# Is there a way to reset Traffic.Stats counters?

Tags: android, android-studio, network-traffic

I would like to know if there is a way to reset to zero each time a button is clicked the counters of Traffic.Stats without reboot the phone for API 23 and forward? For example reset to zero `getTotalRxBytes`.

If not possible, how would be an alternative way to do it?

When the app is closed and open again the counter begin from zero. So, how to do the same without closing the app?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure exactly if there is a way to reset this. But you could always keep the state of the counter onClick and then compare it with Traffic.Stats to find what changed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll have in mind. Meanwhile I'll wait if someone else knows about other method.

Answer (score 1):

I have just did this successfully today.
Put below code in your service.

```
if (currentTime.compareTo("00:00:00 AM")==0)
{
startOfDayWifi= 
(android.net.TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes()+                  
android.net.TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes()) 
/(1e+6);
}

For current time:
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat df = new 
SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ssa");
String currentTime = df.format(c.getTime());

TodaydataWifi =         ((android.net.TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes()+                
      android.net.TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes()) 
      /(1e+6))-startOfDayWifi;

TodayDataWifi will give you the total wifi usage of        today and it will be 0 on next day. 

If you have some confusion about code, feel free to     ask.
```

Comment: Thanks Muhammad for your example. That would work only when new day begins for what I see. What I want is to reset to zero each time I do click on a button. What I see is the counters reset to zero automatically when phone reboots or when the app is closed. So, maybe a way "to close" internally the app without close on display could work(so won't be perceived by user) I hope make sense